# Jquery Rebind Click Using New .on() Instead of .live

Tags: jquery, click, bind

I am having trouble getting the new .on click to work using 1.7.

For dynamically created links, such as the ones generated by clicking the Create button, those links need the same click function as the static links in the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function createDivs(){
content = '<div class="tile-button"><a class="tile-action" href="#" rel="1234" alt="Open">Dynamic Link</a></div>';
$(content).appendTo("#dynamicArea");
$('.tile-action').bind('click',function(){});

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#createButton').on("click", createDivs);

    $('#destroyButton').on("click", function(event){
        $("#dynamicArea").html("");
    });

    $('.tile-action').on("click", function(event){
            var linkalt = $(this).attr("alt");
            var linkrel = $(this).attr("rel");
            alert(linkalt + " " + linkrel);
            return false;
   });
});     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="createButton">CREATE</button> <button id="destroyButton">Destroy :(</button>
<div id="dynamicArea"></div>

<br>
<a class="tile-action" href="#" rel="1234" alt="Open">Link</a><!-- works -->
</body>
</html>
```

In this simplified example of my problem, when you click the Create button a dynamic link appears. When you click that nothing happens and those dynamic links do not call the alert like the static link does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`on` method takes second argument as the selector on which the event should be triggered which you are missing. Also the root element should be the container which will contain the dynamic elements. In your case it is `#dynamicArea`. Try this.

```
   $("#dynamicArea").on("click", ".tile-action", function(event){
            var linkalt = $(this).attr("alt");
            var linkrel = $(this).attr("rel");
            alert(linkalt + " " + linkrel);
            return false;
   });
```

You should understand the working of `on`. We are selecting `#dynamicArea` element and using `on` method on it passing the selector `.tile-action`. jQuery will attach a click event on `#dynamicArea` and whenever any element is clicked inside `#dynamicArea` the event will be bubbled to `#dynamicArea`. At this point it will try to see if the selector which we have passed as second parameter to `on` matches or not. If it matches then it triggers the event otherwise it will not do anything just bubble up the event if we don't stop it.

Comment: Hmm... I am just trying to get .tile-action clicks to trigger each time. I wouldn't want to attach the click to dynamicArea, since there will be other things in there.

Comment: That is what my code will do. I just tried to explain you how `on` works. Don't worry the `click` will only work on `.tile-action` links.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I think you were missing a comma between the second and third parameter (after ".tile-action") When I added that comma it worked great. Thanks again